# HighCharts Semi-Pie Circle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to build a [Semi-pie](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle) chart in HighCharts. I need to provide only 1 value to the semi-circle with value `45%`, in this case Firfox is 45%.  I want that when I provide only 1 value , it should actually render the pie circle for only 45%, not the whole 100%. How can I do that?

Here is my [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-semi-circle/)

Comment: One possibility is to use two values: one 45% and the other 55%. And set color the same as background for 55% value.

Comment: No. That wont work. Any better soluion?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want: see example [at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4r5N/1/)

End angle is calculated as proportion of 45*180/100 = 81. So, end angle is at -9.

```
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: -9,
            center: ['50%', '75%']
```

And data is only one value:

```
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0]
        ]
```

And tooltip is changed to show 45% instead of 100%

```
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
    },
```

**Update:** Used idea from @Mark to calculate `endData` using input `data` (see Mark's comment in his answer). Added also variable for `startAngle`. See update [at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4r5N/3/):

```
var data = 45;
var startAngle = -90;
var endAngle = (data/100 * 180) + startAngle;
endAngle = endAngle == 0 ? 0.01 : endAngle;
...
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
...
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   data]
...
```

Comment: I understand that tooltip value changes from 100 to 45, but my actual concern is if I provide any value , it will still occupy the same space, for eg:- if provide 100 or 45, it will still render the same pie.No difference except from tooltip value. I rather want that if I provide value 20, then the graph should be rendered for only 20%, if 100 then full 100%. Does this kind of thing can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Not to steal @AntoJurković's thunder but his idea in the comment is the simplest way to accomplish what you want.

Here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8EJk/).

The important parts are:

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [                
            {y: 45, name: 'Firefox'},
            {y: 55, color: 'transparent',dataLabels:{enabled: false}} // instead of the background color, use transparent, and disable dataLabels
        ]
  }]
```

and

```
   tooltip: {
        formatter: function(){
            if (this.point.color == "transparent") {
                return false; // suppress the tooltips if it has no color
            } else {                    
                return this.series.name + ':<b>' + this.point.percentage +'%</b>';
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Thumbs up.  Since this is a horizontal half-pie chart, can I make it vertical?

Comment: But it's still not ethical , because there actually exists another value 55 which should not exists. Is there any standard way to do this?

Comment: Not ethical?  To the consumer (viewer) of the pie chart, there is no value 55.  You are in no way misrepresenting the data.  The only other way I can see to do what you want is what @AntoJurković suggests below.  But as you point out there, you'll have to calculate the appropriate `endAngle` for your percentage.

Comment: @Mark: nice solution. Do you know which variable I have to use to calculate `endAngle` in my answer? It depends on series data value which is in this case 45.

Comment: @AntoJurković, the math is `var data = 45; var endAngle = (data/100 * 180) - 90; endAngle = endAngle == 0 ? 0.01 : endAngle;`  The 0 check is to prevent an endAngle of 0, which seems to fill the whole 360 degrees.  Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/W4r5N/2/,  feel free to update your answer with this information.